# Can't get values to dropdown from LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, local-storage

I have stored values from a html-form to localstorage and when I get the data back from localstorage to form for editing, data will come to input-text fields like it should, but not to dropdown or checkbox fields.

What do I need to do to get values also in dropdowns or checkbox fields? Checkbox has multiple values saved as array so those needs to be separated.

```js
if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty('key')) {
  $(function editform() {
    var lsdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
    $('#formid').val(lsdata.FormID);
    $('#createdate').val(lsdata.CreateDate);
    $('#formfiller').val(lsdata.FormFiller);
    $('#customerlist').val(lsdata.CustomerName); //dropdown
    $('#contact').val(lsdata.CustomerContact);
    $('#worklist').val(lsdata.WorkName); //dropdown
    $('#readytodate').val(lsdata.ReadyToDate);
    $('#instructions').val(lsdata.Instructions);
    $('#amount').val(lsdata.Amount);
    $('#amountpcs').val(lsdata.PcsAmount);
    $('#chargefull').val(lsdata.ChargeFull);
    $('#chargepcs').val(lsdata.ChargeByPcs);
    $('#freightcost').val(lsdata.FreightCost);
    $('#materiallist').val(lsdata.MaterialName); //checkbox with multiple options

// localstorage value
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Customer": null,
  "Material": null,
  "Status": null,
  "Work": null,
  "FormID": 150,
  "CreateDate": "2019-09-17T00:00:00",
  "FormFiller": "JOkuMuu",
  "CustomerID": null,
  "CustomerName": "Wsoy",
  "CustomerContact": "Masa",
  "WorkID": null,
  "WorkName": "Lajitelmapakkaus",
  "ReadyToDate": "2019-09-19T00:00:00",
  "Instructions": "Tarkasta kirjat ",
  "Amount": 50,
  "PcsAmount": null,
  "ChargeFull": null,
  "ChargeByPcs": null,
  "FreightCost": null,
  "MaterialID": null,
  "MaterialName": "Xpohja,Tarra",
  "WorkHoursWR": null,
  "WorkHoursIT": null,
  "WorkHoursCS": null,
  "StatusID": null
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want the localstorage to store the selected values *as well as* all available options in a select and multi-checkbox list?

Comment: Also note that you should not be defining functions in a jQuery object. Move the `editform` definition to it's own statement.

Comment: You are storing all selections from a multi-select as a string. You should be storing an array, so you can deserialise it into an array again

Comment: `$('#customerlist').empty().append(lsdata.CustomerName.split(',').map(c => new Option(c, c)));` if `CustomerName` (or the var where the names are) is a comma-separated list

Comment: @acdcjunior Thanks, that worked for dropdowns, but not for checkbox.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, I don't want localstorage to store all values, only checked values. When editing form, I want stored values to be checked again. Other values that are coming from database, should not be checked. Maybe I need to do some function for that, but still learning so everything is bit difficult :)

Answer (score 0):

You use `hasOwnProperty` which is not a method specific to `LocalStorage` but `Object`. Instead, you should use `setItem/getItem` methods of `LocalStorage`

```js
// localstorage value
var data = {
  "$id": "1",
  "Customer": null,
  "Material": null,
  "Status": null,
  "Work": null,
  "FormID": 150,
  "CreateDate": "2019-09-17T00:00:00",
  "FormFiller": "JOkuMuu",
  "CustomerID": null,
  "CustomerName": "Wsoy",
  "CustomerContact": "Masa",
  "WorkID": null,
  "WorkName": "Lajitelmapakkaus",
  "ReadyToDate": "2019-09-19T00:00:00",
  "Instructions": "Tarkasta kirjat ",
  "Amount": 50,
  "PcsAmount": null,
  "ChargeFull": null,
  "ChargeByPcs": null,
  "FreightCost": null,
  "MaterialID": null,
  "MaterialName": "Xpohja,Tarra",
  "WorkHoursWR": null,
  "WorkHoursIT": null,
  "WorkHoursCS": null,
  "StatusID": null
}


localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(data));


if (fetchedData = localStorage.getItem('key')) {
  console.log('Item found!', fetchedData);
}else{
  console.log('Item NOT found!');
}
```

Note that, this snippet won't work since `same origin` error will be thrown.

Hope this helps.